# Find Apple Watch advertising data from another Apple Watch over BLE to calculate distance

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, watchkit, core-bluetooth, watchos, cbcentralmanager

I want to catch advertising data (eg. Watch name and RSSI) from another Apple Watch, over BLE. We know that using BLE on Apple Watch can only do Central. They do not need to be connected, just to catch each other advertising data and calculate distance based on RSSI. I have formula for transfering RSSI values to distance.

How to make Central on one Watch to advertise (data and RSSI) and get those data on another Watch Central that is advertising Name and RSSI?

The code below is using **peripheral**. How to do it with **central**?

```
// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. 
// This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("Peripheral: \(peripheral.name), RSSI: \(rssi)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I can also use watch as peripheral to advertise data:
[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising][1]